# Possible to join two recordsets using VBA/ADO?

Tags: ms-access, ado

The goal is to join an Access table with matching data from a SQL Server table. I would do this using linked tables in Access but I'm running into Access' BigInt problem (I would have a view created to cast BigInt as Int but that isn't an option right now).

So I've been trying to create two recordsets and join them in VBA/ADO. The left side of the join would be the Access table with Season and WeekNum and the right side of the join would be the SQL Server table with Season and Weeknum and other data. This works fine until I try to create a third recordset that is the result of the join (in this example, I haven't tried to do a join, just the first part of the join by selecting from the Access recordset). I'm getting a Type Mismatch error on the line when I do Set ObjRecordset3 = "SELECT * FROM " & Access_Recordset '.

Is it even possible to join two recordsets? If so, how is this done?

```
Function Join()

    Dim SQL_Server_Connection As ADODB.Connection
    Set SQL_Server_Connection = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim SQL_Server_Query As String
    Dim SQL_Server_Recordset As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim Access_Recordset As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim ObjConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Set ObjConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Dim ObjRecordset3 As New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Get data from Bump Table 3:
    Access_Recordset.Open "SELECT * FROM [Bump Table 3]", CurrentProject.Connection

    ' Open connection to SQL Server:
    SQL_Server_Connection_String = "DSN=MySQLServer"
    SQL_Server_Connection.Open SQL_Server_Connection_String

    ' Define the SQL Server query:
    SQL_Server_Query = "SELECT Season, WeekNum FROM TE"

    ' Populate the SQL_Server_Recordset:
    SQL_Server_Recordset.Open SQL_Server_Query, SQL_Server_Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    'Join Access_Recordset (Table: Bump Table 3) to SQL_Server_Recordset (Table: TE)
    Set ObjRecordset3 = "SELECT * FROM " & Access_Recordset ' Type Mismatch error on this line

    Access_Recordset.Close
    Set Access_Recordset = Nothing

    SQL_Server_Recordset.Close
    Set SQL_Server_Recordset = Nothing

    SQL_Server_Connection.Close

End Function
```

*** UPDATE ***

I figured out how to get to my ultimate goal which was to get data about a list of account numbers in an Access table from SQL Server based on the account number field which is common to both tables.  Realizing that I can create a persistent temp table on SQL Server, I used a combination of DAO and ADO to get the values from the Access table and create a temp table. All I had to do then is run the pass-through query which references the temp table. The only odd thing (which is not a problem at this point) is if I create the temp table and run the pass-through query in VBA, this setup works. But if I create the temp table in VBA and double-click on the pass-through query, Access says that the temp table can't be found. Anyway, here's the code:

```
Public Sub Insert_Into_Access_From_ADO_Recordset_Using_PTQ_Simpler()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

    'Open SQL Server
    Dim str_cnn As String
    str_cnn = "MYDSN"

    cnn.Open str_cnn

    ' Drop the temp table:

        Dim str_SQL_Drop_Temp_Table As String

        str_SQL_Drop_Temp_Table = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##BumpData','U') IS NOT NULL "
        str_SQL_Drop_Temp_Table = str_SQL_Drop_Temp_Table & " DROP TABLE ##BumpData "

        cnn.Execute str_SQL_Drop_Temp_Table


    ' Create the temp table:

        Dim str_SQL_Create_Temp_Table As String

        str_SQL_Create_Temp_Table = " CREATE TABLE ##BumpData "
        str_SQL_Create_Temp_Table = str_SQL_Create_Temp_Table & " " & "("
        str_SQL_Create_Temp_Table = str_SQL_Create_Temp_Table & " " & " ID INT "
        str_SQL_Create_Temp_Table = str_SQL_Create_Temp_Table & " " & " ,   AccountNumber VARCHAR(Max)"
        str_SQL_Create_Temp_Table = str_SQL_Create_Temp_Table & " " & ")"

        cnn.Execute str_SQL_Create_Temp_Table


    ' Insert values from the Access table into the temp table
    ' by looping through the Access table as a recordset:

        Dim rst_DAO As DAO.Recordset
        Set rst_DAO = dbs.OpenRecordset("Bump Data")

        Dim str_SQL_Insert As String

        rst_DAO.MoveFirst

        With rst_DAO
            Do While Not rst_DAO.EOF
                'str_Loan_Number_List = str_Loan_Number_List & "'" & Trim(rst![Loan Number]) & "'" & ","
                str_SQL_Insert = " INSERT INTO ##BumpData VALUES (" & rst_DAO![ID] & ",'" & Trim(rst_DAO![Loan Number]) & "') "
                cnn.Execute str_SQL_Insert
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End With

    ' Run the pass-thru query which joins to the temp table:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO [Bump Results] FROM [Bump PTQ]"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Comment: The `Big Int` problem with linked tables only happens in dynaset mode as Access doesn't support numeric fields to the same level. As long as you only need use it in a query for reference and not update the data then you could create an access query from the linked table and set the mode to `Snapshot`, or failing that perhaps a `Pass through query`.

Comment: @MattDonnan I don't understand your comment.  When I create a query on my linked table which includes the field expression `TypeName(bigint_fld)`, it replies "String" from either snapshot or dynaset modes.  I thought the question was about joining an Access integer field with a SQL Server Big Int field.

Comment: @HansUp You are correct, the reason I mentioned it was because I remember in 2003, if you opened up a linked table which used the `BigInt` as a `PK` then you could often see a stream of `#Deleted` rather than the data due to the dynaset mode not been able to process the precision, viewing in snapshot negated this problem and I though perhaps it may cause an issue when trying to link tables in a query also. Although unrelated to the immediate problem with the question I though it may come in handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reported this line triggers the error:

```vba
Set ObjRecordset3 = "SELECT * FROM " & Access_Recordset
```

The right side of the `=` sign attempts to concatenate a string with an `ADODB.Recordset` object.  That is probably the immediate cause of the compile error.  However, that's not the only problem with that line. `Set <recordset object> = "any string value"` will not work.  And finally, Access SQL does not support *`FROM <recordset object>`* for any type of recordset object (ADO or DAO).

I think you should look for a simpler approach.  In following query, `dbo_BigIntTable` is an ODBC link to a SQL Server table.  It includes a field, `bigint_fld`, whose SQL Server data type is BigInt.  However, Access sees that field as Text type.  Therefore I can join it with the string equivalent of a Long Integer field (`tblFoo.id`).

```sql
SELECT tblFoo.id, dbo_BigIntTable.bigint_fld
FROM
    tblFoo
    INNER JOIN dbo_BigIntTable
    ON CStr(tblFoo.id) = dbo_BigIntTable.bigint_fld;
```

The Access query designer complained it can't display that join in Design View, but I was able create the join from SQL View and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for this. Sorry for the delay in replying.